# Sql Server Self JOIN (pushing column values down)

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I am asked to do the following: 
"CycleStartDate needs to be the BillDate from the previous BillDate record. If a previous record does not exist, you should use the most recent CycleEndDate from the DataTime table"

CycleStartDate and CycleEndDate are columns in a table called DataTime

BillDate is a column in a table called BillingData

This is the BillDate values:

```
2012-07-27 00:00:00.000
2012-07-27 00:00:00.000
2012-08-27 00:00:00.000
2012-08-27 00:00:00.000
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000
2012-10-26 00:00:00.000
2012-10-26 00:00:00.000
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-12-27 00:00:00.000
```

How would I set the CycleStartDate values based on the requirements?
The tables Datetime and BillingData are connected by a column called MeterID.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this...

```
SELECT B.BillDate, 
       ISNULL(
              B2.BillDate, 
              (SELECT MAX(CycleEndDate) FROM DataTime DT WHERE DT.MeterID = B.MeterID)
             )  CycleStartDate 
    FROM BillingData B
    OUTER APPLY (
                 SELECT TOP 1 B2.BillDate 
                        FROM BillingData B2 
                        WHERE B2.MeterID = B.MeterID AND 
                              B2.BillingData < B.BillingData 
                        ORDER BY B2.BillingData DESC
                ) B2
```

I still have one doubt... Do you need to take the `SELECT MAX(CycleEndDate) FROM DataTime DT WHERE DT.MeterID = B.MeterID` or the `SELECT MAX(CycleEndDate) FROM DataTime DT WHERE DT.MeterID = B.MeterID AND DT.CycleEndDate < B.BillDate`?

But it can be done without the OUTER APPLY...

```
SELECT B.BillDate, 
       ISNULL(
              (SELECT MAX(B2.BillDate) 
                      FROM BillingData B2 
                      WHERE B2.MeterID = B.MeterID AND 
                            B2.BillingData < B.BillingData),

              (SELECT MAX(CycleEndDate) FROM DataTime DT WHERE DT.MeterID = B.MeterID)
             )  CycleStartDate 
       FROM BillingData B
```

I think the second version is quite readable... For each row of BillingData B, look for the biggest `BillDate` (`MAX(B2.BillDate)`) lesser than the current `BillDate` and of the same `MeterID`. If not present (the `ISNULL`, if the first one is not present then it's `NULL`, so it goes to the second part of the `ISNULL`), look for the biggest `CycleEndDate` from `DataTime` with the same `MeterID` and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for offsetting a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.BillDate, COALESCE(b.BillDate,c.CycleEndDate) 'CycleEndDate'
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MeterID ORDER BY BillDate DESC)'RowRank'
      FROM YourTable
     )a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MeterID ORDER BY BillDate DESC)'RowRank'
           FROM YourTable
           )b
      ON a.RowRank = b.RowRank - 1
      AND a.MeterID = b.MeterID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MeterID,MAX(CycleEndDate)'CycleEndDate'
           FROM DataTime
           GROUP BY MeterID
          ) c
    ON a.MeterID = c.MeterID
```

The `PARTITION BY` may not be necessary as well as the `MeterID` criteria in the `JOIN`, your wording is a little confusing as to whether the `ORDER BY` should be ascending or descending, as it is above the newest record will be the one that gets it's date from the DateTime table, remove `DESC` to make it the oldest record that gets it's value from that table.