# SQL Server Inserting a previous value into the new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables:

Table1:
CustomerName BillDate

```
CITY - BEAUTIFICATION LM            2013-05-30 00:00:00.000
CITY - BEAUTIFICATION LM            2013-06-28 00:00:00.000
CITY - PARKS/RT 66                  2012-07-12 00:00:00.000
CITY - PARKS/RT 66                  2012-07-12 00:00:00.000
```

and so on...

Table2 has the field: CycleStartDate

I want to insert the data from Table1 to Table2 as the following:
For each unique customerName, CycleStartDate is the BillDate from the previous record. If a previous record does not exist, replace the NULL with 2013-07-1 00:00:00.000.

Is it possible that we can do something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "Bill Date from the previous record"?Are you trying to say that if there are 2 dates for a customer then the lesser date should be selected? For example in case of customer "CITY - BEAUTIFICATION LM" CyclestartDate should be "2013-05-30 00:00:00.000"

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193104/sql-server-self-join-pushing-column-values-down
Should revise original rather than post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SQL Server less then 2012, try this

```
select T.CustomerName, isnull(TP.BillDate, '20130701') as CycleStartDate
from Table1 as T
   outer apply (
       select top 1 T2.BillDate
       from Table1 as T2
       where T2.CustomerName = T.CustomerName and T2.BillDate < T.BillDate
       order by T2.BillDate desc
   ) as TP
```

if you have SQL Server 2012, see [LAG()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)  function

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is one way assuming SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  CustomerName,
            BillDate,
            RN1=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerName ORDER BY BillDate),
            RN2=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerName ORDER BY BillDate DESC)
    FROM dbo.Table1
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(CustomerName, CycleStartDate)
SELECT  CustomerName,
        CASE WHEN RN2 = 1 THEN '20130701' ELSE CycleStartDate END
FROM CTE
WHERE RN1 = 1
```